# How To Deploy MSIX In Another PC

Tags: c#, xaml, desktop-application, winui-3, msix

I have created a winUi 3 desktop application. I have publish that application using sideloading and it has generated a **MSIX** package for installation.
When I'm installing and running that package in my PC it's working fine but when I installing that package in another pc (my friends pc) it installed but when I'm lunching that application it gives error
[image]

Is that compulsory to have a dotnet to launch MSIX application??

Comment: You do not need dotnet for `MSIX`. You need dotnet for `App1.exe`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Markus Meyer in his comment, you need dotnet for your application, not MSIX.

Basically you now have two options for your application with MSIX:

1. Require dotnet to be installed on your target machine(s) as prerequisite
2. Publish you application as self contained (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained)

This previous question may also help: [MSIX: How to achieve automatic install of .net 5 required for my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638459/msix-how-to-achieve-automatic-install-of-net-5-required-for-my-application), especially this link https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/msix/msix-how-to-achieve-automatic-install-of-net-5-required-for-my/m-p/2372896/highlight/true#M880 for details from the above discussion.